# Direct2D Only Partially Linking in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, graphics, linker, c++builder, direct2

I've got a C++ Builder (Rad Studio Berlin) project setup to use Direct2d. Canvas drawing works just fine with the TDirect2DCanvas which would indicate Direct2D is linking properly. Everything renders smoothly. However, I need to use a matrix. I get linking error when I try to. For example, when try I:

```
canvas->RenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(15.0, D2D1PointF(100, 100)));
```

...I get the following linking error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'D2D1MakeRotateMatrix' referenced from C:\DP\TRUNK\SRC\CLIENTSIDE\APPLICATIONS\VIEWER\WIN32\DEBUG\MIMAGE.OBJ
```

C++ builder was supposed to already be setup to link against direct2d if I just include the headers. Can anyone help me link against the appropriate files in the C++ Builder way?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution from a different source. Here it is:

After some research, this issue has not been determined to be a bug.

> For many of the standard Windows API functions, the IDE will add the correct library automatically so that the dependencies on the function references will be satisfied.  With DirectX (which is somewhat uncommonly used), the IDE does not automatically supply the library which corresponds to the header file, so this is causing the unresolved linker errors.
>
> The solution is to either (as I mentioned previously) add the D2D1.lib to the project, or statically reference it in code:

```
// as long as D2D1.lib is on the library search path, it should be found
#pragma comment(lib,"D2D1.lib")
```

> Some developers add the above line of code to their headers and so all you need to do is include the header and all is well... the DirectX team did not do this and hence the unresolved linker errors.

Hope this clarifies the issue,