# Font orientation in TDirect2DCanvas is not working?

Tags: delphi, orientation, direct2d

I need to draw angled text on TDirect2DCanvas, but no success.

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
const
  myText = 'Kikimor';
begin
   LCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Canvas, ClientRect);
   LCanvas.BeginDraw;
   try
     LCanvas.Font.Orientation := 90;
     LCanvas.TextOut(100,100,myText);
   finally
     LCanvas.EndDraw;
     LCanvas.Free;
   end;
end;
```

No matter what angle I give for orientation, it always draws a straight text.
Is orientation not working or I need to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting TDirect2DCanvas.Font.Orientation does not have any effect (most likely not implemented, sorry, no time to debug). Direct2D wrapper supplied in Delphi is very basic.

To achieve your goal, apply transformation by hand:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
  currentTransform: TD2D1Matrix3x2F;
  ptf: TD2DPoint2f;
const
  myText = 'Kikimor';
begin
  LCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(self.Canvas, ClientRect);
  LCanvas.BeginDraw;
  try
//    backup the current transformation
    LCanvas.RenderTarget.GetTransform(currentTransform);
    ptf.x:= 100.0; ptf.y:= 100.0;  //rotation center point
// apply transformation to rotate text at 90 degrees:
    LCanvas.RenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2D1Matrix3x2F.Rotation(90, ptf));
// draw the text (rotated)
    LCanvas.TextOut(100, 100, myText);
// restore the original transform
    LCanvas.RenderTarget.SetTransform(currentTransform);
  finally
    LCanvas.EndDraw;
    LCanvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For more extensive information/effects you can look at:
[Drawing text using the IDWriteTextLayout.Draw()](https://www.cnblogs.com/del/archive/2011/04/13/2014946.html)
The whole [Direct2D](https://www.cnblogs.com/del/category/290814.html) category at the same site is also interesting (use Google Translate).

Answer (score 1):

For those using C++ Builder I got this to work:

```cpp
#include <Vcl.Direct2D.hpp>

// needed for the D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation transform
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment(lib,"D2D1.a")
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"D2D1.lib")
#endif

TD2DPoint2f point; // rotation centre
point.x = 100.0;
point.y = 100.0;

canvas_2d->RenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(90, point));
canvas_2d->TextOut(100, 100, text);

// restore 0 rotation afterwards
canvas_2d->RenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(0, point));
```

Note that trying to use GetTransform like in the Delphi version causes an exception, so I cleared the transform by passing it a new one with zero rotation, there may be a better way to do this.

The pragma is needed due to a link error, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000829/direct2d-only-partially-linking-in-c-builder) for details.